# Why do I get the error "Reached end of file while parsing"?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class Overload
{
    void average(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        average= (a+b+c)/3;
    }
    void average(int d, int e, double a, double b)
    {
        average= (d+e+a+b)/4;
    }
    void average(double c,double d,double e,double f,double g)
    {
        average= (c+d+e+f+g)/5;
}

class mainOverload
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Overload object=new Overload();
        object.average(7, 5, 1);
        object.average(15, 12, 15.12, 12.15);
        object.average(7.7, 8.4, 30.2, 1.4, 6.4);
    }
}
```

Comment: im trying to find average for each method..but when i compile it..i get this error..help me pls ...its Overloading Method

Comment: When you get this error, use the formatter in your editor to indent the braces correctly, and you will most likely spot your omission immediately.  Then fix it, and reformat again.

Comment: Oh ya..thx ...i overlooked that path..and now i repair it..and when i compile..i have this new ERROR. "cannot find symbol variable average"...oh man...java give me lot of error...im new in Java ... :(

Comment: use "return" instead of assigning to average

Comment: @Ezwan: do you come from Visual Basic (or another Basic dialect)? It's the only language I know of where the return value of a method is defined via assignment.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to close the 3rd `average` method:

```
void average(double c,double d,double e,double f,double g)
    {
        average= (c+d+e+f+g)/5;
    } // << here
```

Regarding your comment - you haven't declare a variable called `average` and yet you try to use it in each of the average methods. Declare this variable as a class field or a method field to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the closing brace of the method `average` with 5 `double` parameters.

This way the compiler interprets the class closing brace as the method closing brace, `mainOverload` as a nested class and is missing the final closing brace for the `Overload` class.

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot the closing bracket `}` for the class `Overload`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthesis for the

```
average(double c,double d,double e,double f,double g)
```

method.
This should be

```
void average(double c,double d,double e,double f,double g)
    {
        average= (c+d+e+f+g)/5;
    }//Missing!
```

Answer (score 0):

A bracket is left here

```
     {
            average= (c+d+e+f+g)/5;
     } // !!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> have this new ERROR. "cannot find symbol variable average"...

The problem is that you are assigning to a variable that you haven't declared.

```
void average(double c,double d,double e,double f,double g)
{
    average= (c+d+e+f+g)/5;  // <<<=== you haven't declared the 'average' variable.
}
```

But even if you do, your `average` methods don't make a lot of sense.  It would be better to declare the methods as **returning** the average or their arguments; e.g.

```
double average(double c,double d,double e,double f,double g)
{
    return (c+d+e+f+g)/5;
}
```

and then call them like this (for example)

```
System.out.println(average(7.7, 8.4, 30.2, 1.4, 6.4));
```

> oh man...java give me lot of error...im new in Java ... :(

Yup.  You seem to be trying to learn by trial and error.  This is a BAD IDEA.  It will be slow and frustrating, and you will fail to recognize / understand important concepts and practices that are second nature to properly educated programmers.

You need to buy and read a Java textbook and do the exercises.

(For instance, your text book will explain how you can avoid having to write a bazillion different `average` methods with different numbers and types of arguments.)